# const function parameters and default behavior

Tags: c++, coding-style, parameters

Say I have a C++ function

```
/**
 * @param path If empty, the system default is used
 */
void foo(const std::string& path);
```

And in my implementation I have a default handling for empty `path`s

```
void foo(const std::string& path) {
    if (path.empty()) {
        // Use some default
    } else {
        // Use the given path
    }
}
```

However, the if-else blocks are quite the same so I would either write

#### A

```
void foo(const std::string& path_) {
    const std::string& path = path_.empty() ? "some default" : path_;
    // Use the given path
}
```

#### B

or change the function definition altogether:

```
void foo(std::string path) {
    if (path.empty() {
        path = "some default";
    }
    // Use the given path
}
```

Now I am wondering what is advised in terms of style in such cases:

- **A** seems a little odd at first because I explicitly made the parameter const and now start to somehow "rewrite" it. Would this code look like overkill?
- **B** seems a little odd because then, this function would have a different signature just because of some implementation details. It would stand out from the other functions which still use `const&`

Comment: Hi. This question should rather go on SO. However, you should never change the signature (i.e. interface) to satisfy some internal implementation details.

Comment: @Christophe That's too absolute. Yes, you should generally prefer ease-of-use over ease-of-implementation, but choosing the right way to balance and reconcile them is an art, and includes selecting the signature and contract.

Answer (score 4):

Unless there is a good reason not to (meaning your string needs the terminator), I would prefer changing the signature:

```
void foo(std::string_view path)
```

It potentially increases efficiency for the caller *and* the callee.

And doing

```
if (path.empty())
    path = "some default";
```

is thereafter efficient and the obvious thing to do.

Go for a good interface first, a good implementation second. Adjusting the interface can be beneficial for efficiency, but be careful not to let too many implementation-details bleed into the interface, nor to compromise usability more than warranted.

As an aside, there is a third option you didn't mention, namely tail-recursion:

```
void foo(const std::string& path) {
    const static std::string default_path = "some_default";
    if (path.empty())
        return foo(defauult_path);
    // Use the given path
}
```

Comment: I understand that you're talking about rvalue optimizarion in your first example? Just be careful that you need "modern" c++ for it to works. Some unfortunate souls still work with c++98

Comment: @JayZ No, the first example only needs the C++17 reference-type `std::string_view`. There are backports to at least C++11, I don't think going further down is too hard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a bit weird to change the signature of a function because of the implementation. I would prefer option A because of the mentioned reason and because it is more restrictive.

Assuming the function parameter is used to open a file at a given path, it makes a lot of sense to declare it const. But I also see no reason to use pass-by-reference using the reference symbol '&' when the parameter is already declared const. If you, for example, were to use the parameter to open a file, you just need the value. If you want to change the value of the parameter, then it makes sense, but then it should not be declared const.